# Change the basic configuration of ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Two simples questions, how to change the basic configuration of ruby on rails?
Two things that I need to add:
I want to use mysql by default, now I use this command:

```
rails new projet_name -d mysql
```

and how to add gem by default?
I use the thin server and I would like it included in my gem file by default.

I look in my system but I did not find the skeleton

```
atmoner-laptop:~/$ whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 
/usr/lib/ruby 
/usr/bin/X11/ruby 
/usr/bin/X11/ruby1.8 
/usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rails offer the possibility to use skeleton templates. A quick search gave me http://www.railsboost.com/templates/new and http://railsapps.github.com/rails-composer/, but I know there is many others, and one of theme is probably better suited for your needs.

Comment: Awesome! I'll try to configure it with the gem I want to use, thanks for info ksol